# Mod-deleted answer is hidden on mobile but not on desktop?

Tags: bug, flagging, deleted-questions, mobile-web

A (meta) answer was deleted by a moderator. When I view it on desktop, it merely appears to be deleted, but when I view it on mobile the content of the answer is hidden with a text saying

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

If you don't have a mobile phone but have more than 10k reputation, you can click on "mobile" at the bottom of the page to switch to the mobile site to test it out.

Considering the content of the answer, this isn't surprising that some people flagged it as offensive, which I guess triggered the behavior. But 1/ shouldn't the mod deletion have overridden that and 2/ why is the behavior different on desktop and mobile?

Comment: Only the developers can answer why they chose to code the mobile app in such a way that such posts are not shown. May be they wanted to optimize bandwidth consumption or some such resource? I don't know. I just feel like I should reiterate the obvious point that even moderator deleted posts should be shown to trusted users. This is to enable crowd control on moderation, and that should not be compromised.

Comment: But what about the need to edit out the offensive material from the said post? Another moderator did that later (in response to yet another flag). But, as you all know, you don't need a diamond to do such editing...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If a post is deleted because it was flagged as offensive by 5(?) users, its text is normally hidden both on desktop and mobile from the people who can see it (with the text I quoted shown instead). Viewing the revision history (e.g. by clicking on the link) shows what the post was in any case, it's not inaccessible. What I guess happened here is that some people flagged as offensive, then you deleted it before it reached the required numbers of flags to be auto-deleted, and this resulted in the weird situation. IMO it's a bug.

Comment: That's possible. I don't know the details of the auto-deletion process (apparently I haven't paid attention). In retrospect I should have acted to black out the offensive parts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [For more info.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: If I remember this correctly, it is a limitation of the SE API that simply doesn't return deleted questions. The mobile apps use the same public API that is available to everyone else.

Comment: @MadScientist It's not a mobile app, it's really the mobile site. You can test it out on a desktop browser.

Comment: IMO it is better that this thread is dedicated to discussion/explanations of the SW behavior re deleted posts (as also prompted by flaggers). Otherwise it is likely to devolve into a free-for-all around a recent disagreement. There were several flags on posts and comments in this thread. I applied admittedly blunt tools in removing some of the dirt in  an attempt to redirect the attention.